# Is it safe to install kernel packages as dependencies on a Linode?

Tags: updates, kernel, yum

I'm working on a Linode:

```
[michael@ads_portals ~]$ uname -r
3.5.2-linode45
```

I need to install some libraries, such as PyQt4-devel:

```
sudo yum install PyQt4-devel
```

Unfortunately, this comes up in the list of dependencies:

```
kernel                    i686    2.6.32-279.9.1.el6            updates   23 M
kernel-firmware           noarch  2.6.32-279.9.1.el6            updates  8.7 M
```

What would be the consequences of going on with the installation?  Would this kernel just sit there and do no harm?  It's not going to replace the existing kernel, is it?  Finally, I already have a 3.5.2 kernel, why is it installing an older 2.6.32 kernel?

Now, if this was my machine, I'd go ahead and install without batting an eyelid.  In this case, the Linode belongs to a customer and I'd prefer not to clown it up.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the customer and got them to OK the install.  Happy to report that all is well so far.